# Como pasar el valor de un campo a una subconsulta?

Tags: mysql

Tengo la siguiente consulta en MySQL, en la que intento colocar el valor de un campo, como valor de otro campo en una subconsulta, pero no se si se pueda hacer lo que necesito, o será necesario buscar una alternativa.

```
SELECT 
campo1, -- necesito el valor de este campo más abajo en el where de la subconsulta
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM funcionarios fu
INNER JOIN jerarquias jq ON (fu.jerarquia_id = jq.id)
INNER JOIN dependencias dp ON (fu.dependencia_id = dp.id)
INNER JOIN ccps cc ON (dp.ccp_id = cc.id)
WHERE jq.jquia = 'CM' AND cc.ccp = **VALOR_DEL_CAMPO_AQUI**
) AS 'CM', 
COUNT(*) AS total 
FROM `dependencias` a 
INNER JOIN ccps b ON (a.ccp_id = b.id) 
INNER JOIN funcionarios c ON (c.dependencia_id = a.id) 
GROUP BY b.ccp;
```

Probe colocando explicitamente el valor en el where y si me funciona, pero la idea sería tratar de utilizar el valor del campo1 de la misma consulta, para que de esta manera sea dinamica la consulta

Comment: ¿Y qué condición debería satisfacer en el `WHERE`? ¿Has mirado algo sobre subconsultas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que entiendo, quieres utilizar el valor de la columna **"campo1"** de la tabla **"dependencias"** de tu consulta principal en el WHERE de la sub-consulta, si es así, **puedes probar llamando a "campo1" con el Alias que le asignaste a la tabla "dependencias" en la consulta principal**

Por ejemplo:

En tu código tienes

```
WHERE jq.jquia = 'CM' AND cc.ccp = **VALOR_DEL_CAMPO_AQUI**
```

Tomando en cuenta que en tu consulta principal contienes la tabla de la siguiente manera

```
SELECT ...
FROM `dependencias` a
```

El valor de la misma consulta podrías insertarlo de la siguiente manera

```
WHERE jq.jquia = 'CM' AND cc.ccp = a.campo1
```

De esta manera insertas el valor de la consulta principal y no el que está referenciado en el INNER JOIN de tu sub-consulta

Comment: Grande eekJaaj, justo el detallito que faltaba jeje. Muchas gracias amigo